# Opencart Extension - Hide Price Until Login - Recode

Tags: php, xml, opencart, vqmod

New to the world Opencart!

I have just installed version 1.5.6.4 and have tried to install an extension in the vQmod folder. It is also worth mentioning that I have tinkered with my own theme (which works) it's called 'mytheme'. In addition, I noticed that the extension that I downloaded was made for older versions. For your reference I have attached a link to the extension.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6136&filter_search=hide%20price&page=2

This extension is spot on for what we need... is there a way to update this in the code to make it work for our needs?
I have also (after trial and error and getting nothing) updated a line of code in the file. This is assuming of course that I haven't missed something along the way.

```
<file name="catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/module/bestseller.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
            onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" />
             ]]></search>
             <add><![CDATA[
             <?php if($this->customer->isLogged()){ ?>onclick="addToCart('<?php echo         $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" /><?php }else{ ?>onclick="alert('Please Login to View      Prices and Add to Cart!');" class="button" /><?php } ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
</file>
```

Any relevant help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I have check your code and it extension. but, It is working fine. I think, you need to * instead of mytheme and try.  `<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/module/bestseller.tpl">`

Comment: Hello thank you for the pointer, I will have a go after the weekend.
What is the star doing in this instance?

Comment: Hello HarnishDesign, thanks for the tip it has worked to some extent although the prices are still being displayed...? Not sure if this is something you can help with or whether it is to do with the extension itself.

Comment: Asking for code does not qualify as a programming question here ... .

Comment: What is the problem with the user base on this website? I have already posted my own snippet and even broke the issue down into to detail - an issue that came about after I tinkered with the code. (Harnish this isn't directed at you and thank you for the help).
For those that truly cared to give my query a read thank you.

Comment: This question is specific to open cart and should be asked on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are using extension for hiding price when there is default feature to do this.

If you don't know login to

```
admin>system>setting>option
```

Under the Account heading
There is a option `Login Display Prices:` enable it

**Added[image]**

Comment: Hello, I just checked the 'options'. I cannot see an 'option' that will allow me to remove the prices. I read it up and down twice.

Comment: I just have re-edited my answer with snapshot

Comment: After all that trawling for extensions, reading posts, recoding bits, it was a simple as that. Thanks Ramesh